# A journal published my private home address alongside my publication. Can I get it removed?

Tags: publications, journals, online-publication, personal-name, privacy

Some years ago, I published an article in a Springer journal. However, when I accessed its online version today, I found out that the publisher has swapped my residential address for my correspondence address. Since I am the corresponding author and this information is public, I am concerned about my security. I have already tried contacting Springer to no avail.

How should I proceed in order to get this issue fixed?

Comment: It generally is not hard to find an address given a name. Public records and such. But, bad form on the journal.

Comment: Usually about 10 people read a paper anyway.

Comment: It's too late to fix it.  The paper is already distributed.  If you want to keep secrets, you need to enforce that at the copyediting stage.

Comment: How did the journal get your residential & correspondence addresses?

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist My residential adress is NOT printed in the paper (only the correct correspondence address can be found in the paper). It is available only in the "Author information" section in the online journal.

Comment: Ah, so copyediting was no help.  Well, it's still too late because the information has been distributed.

Comment: @JonCuster i was thinking that. basically anyone who knows where OP works can just follow the OP home from work and would therefore know OP's address?

Comment: Are you saying the journal basically stalked you to find out where you live and then doxxed you by making your personal address public? This is a very serious breach of privacy. How in the world could that happen?

Comment: Azor Ahai -him  That's not the point though.

Comment: @JohnSmithKyon - much easier than that. A simple web request and a few dollars gets you more information about you than you can imagine. My county has all property information on line in their GIS - who owns the property, the address the property tax bill is sent to, how much the property tax is, when it was paid, ... And you can search on most fields in the GIS.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- But it could be [him](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ted_Kaczynski) reading your papers and sending you packages...

Comment: @Tom It was more reassurance that it probably won't be consequential than an excuse for Springer's actions, since journals tend to not be very active about doing stuff like this.

Comment: @terdon: Stalking seems pretty far-fetched.  Presumably OP (or a co-author, secretary, etc) gave the home address to the journal at some point in the correspondence about the paper — this isn’t unusual, there can be many legitimate reasons for it — and then the journal mixed up the home address and institutional address in their system.  It’s a privacy breach to be sure, but it’s well within the realm of everyday incompetence.

Comment: @PLL fair enough, that does sound far more likely. I have never given my home address to a journal, nor can I think of good reasons to, but if you say there are I'm sure you're right.

Comment: @PLL that's exactly what happened

Comment: @JonCuster oh thanks for the info...that's really legal in your county?

Comment: @JohnSmithKyon - Absolutely. Many things are considered public records. The difference is that once upon a time you had to go down to the county office and ask for help, now they are all digitized and readily available. No more security through obscurity. But things like land ownership, business licenses, criminal records and what not are all public records.

Comment: @JonCuster ah makes a lot of sense. thanks for the info.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Springer has a [privacy policy](https://www.springer.com/gp/privacy-policy). It seems to be largely based on the European Union's *General Data Protection Regulation* (GDPR).

According to XIV, point 2, you can request a removal of your personal data on specific grounds, e.g. because the data are not needed, or because you withdraw your consent. This seems to be the case with you.

You can contact their Data Protection Officer about that (dataprotection@springernature.com). Explain your situation and ask for the data to be removed.

The Data Protection Officer should react swiftly, as there might be grave legal consequences if they violate your data rights ([at least if the EU's GDPR applies to your case](https://gdpr.eu/fines/)).

Comment: Part of me wanted to see their physical address in this answer. Obviously, their correspondence address and not any residential addresses. ;-)

Answer (score 14):

I have the same situation with my email address being published on SpringerLink, and they agreed to remove it. I simply mailed the same person that I had contact with during the proof reading.

The usual process for Springer is to publish an additional paper titled "Correction to ..." (with the same authors) that explains what has changed about the original paper, and mark the latter with "A correction to this article is available". As in your case the original paper was not wrong and did not need to be corrected (in fact, it should not even be changed at all), I would insist on this not happening. Otherwise, the additional article would for example appear on your Google Scholar profile. In my case, Springer agreed to just remove my email address without an additional article after clarifying internally (but the change has not yet been made).